# How can i rebase my branch like this?

Tags: git, github

[image]

i made a branch in 1.1 branch and pushed some code inside it by mistake.

it had to be made in 1.0 branch but i made it in 1.1.

so i want to move the branch like this pic.

what kind of commands do i have to put in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check out branch you already have

```
git checkout $your_branch
```

if you are happy with the name of $your_branch, then proceed to the rebase operation.  If you want a different name them

```
git branch $better_name
git checkout $better_name
```

now use

```
git rebase --onto 1.0 XX
```

You might not need to specify XX, but if you do need do specify the SHA of the bottom-left most commit in your graph.  You can probably also get this by `git merge-base HEAD 1.0`.  There is a chance of course you may have to resolve merge conflicts as well.  Once the rebase ends you are done, although you may want to redo your branch tracking if that is applicable.

Comment: Or, if the name is good, shorten as usual to `git rebase --onto 1.0 XX $your_branch`.